# Mapping an Adjacency List to a Synonym List in Python

Tags: python, mapping, adjacency-list

I have two python dictionaries that are structured as defaultdicts that follow the format {string:set(string)}. 
They are as follows:

```
mnAdjacency = {mnID: set(mnIDs)}
#example- {'D01.021.123':set(['D01','D01.021'], 'G11.456':set(['G11']))
mn2ui = {mnID: set(dUI, cUI)}
#example- {'D01.021.123':set(['D00005', 'C000023']), 'G11.456':set(['D89456', 'C00456'])}
```

I am attempting to map the keys and values of the adjacency list to those of the synonym list while retaining the associations of the adjacency list. This is held in a dictionary of dictionaries to be used for output later on. This dictionary is as follows:

```
meshTerm = {dUI: {'name': 'string','edges': [('is_part_of', 'dUI')]}}
#example- {'D00005': {'name': 'bike','edges': [('is_a', 'D00004')]}, 'C00002': {'name': 'car','edges': [('is_a', 'D00004)]}}
```

My current code tries to hold everything in memory and it hogs memory, resulting in a Kill: 9.

The adjacency list is mnAdjacency and the synonym list is mn2ui.
meshTerm[ui]['edges'] is a defaultdict(dict) that stores all sorts of properties for each ui.

```
 for leaf, branches in mnAdjacency.iteritems():
    for branch in branches:
        startNodes = mn2ui[leaf]
        endNodes = mn2ui[branch]
        for start in startNodes:
            for end in endNodes:
                meshTerm[start]['edges'].append(('is_a', end))
```

Output would be the addition of relationship tuples `('is_a',dUI)` to the meshTerm dictionary.

There must be a smarter way to get around this issue but I think my Google foo is failing me.

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you post some example data, along with expected output.  It's not exactly clear how you want your mapping function to work.

Comment: @andrew_reece Hopefully my edit made the issue more clear?